# Get contents of div with inner div

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="chocs">Chocolate Bar <div class="id">1234</div></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('div#groupinfo .chocs').click(function(){
   alert($(this).slug.text());
});
```

Im trying to get the contents of the inner div (id) when the outer div is clicked.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's what jQuery is for (among other things of course). This solution uses the context parameter, it looks for elements with the class of `id`inside the element that was clicked on by providing `this`as the context object.

```
$('div#groupinfo .chocs').click(function(){
    alert($(".id", this).html());
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3BCUU/)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`children()` method](http://api.jquery.com/children) to target the child div;

```
$('div#groupinfo .chocs').click(function(){
   var contents = $(this).children('.id').text();
});
```

If the inner div ends up not-being-a-direct-child, use [`find()` instead](http://api.jquery.com/find);

```
$('div#groupinfo .chocs').click(function(){
   var contents = $(this).find('.id').text();
});
```

Comment: @freebird: I feel a bit guilty picking up rep for trivial questions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a parent `div` with the id `groupinfo`:

```
$('div#groupinfo .chocs').click(function() {
   alert($(this).find(".id").text());
});​
```

Comment: Yes. That's right. Just to make it clear - `.text()` will get contents inclusive of content contained within child elements.

Comment: instead of find you can use the context parameter for jQuery, it's usually faster. (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the help of `find` like this

```
$('div#groupinfo .chocs').click(function(){
   alert($(this).find('.id').text());
});
```

[Jquery find method](http://api.jquery.com/find/)